# Chatbot that responds to user queries with images

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gradio

I have created a chatbot using gpt3.5 and gradio, I have referred [this](https://github.com/amrrs/chatgpt-clone/blob/main/app.py) for creating it. So my UI is similar to ChatGpt.

I am able to respond to user queries with text output, but unable to respond with images, while maintaining chat history.

Below is my code structure, for some reason, I won't be able to add my complete code, but adding enough to give an idea about it

```
def my_chatbot(question,chat_history):
    # Here it calls the OpenAI API, gets some data, and then sends that data to a function that generates a plot, saves it as an image(xyz.png), and returns the filename
    chat_history.append((question,img_filename))
    return "",chat_history
    



with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.ClearButton([msg, chatbot])
    msg.submit(my_chatbot, [msg, chatbot],[gr.Image(type="filepath"),chatbot])

demo.launch()
```

Now when I run this code and write a query on gradio UI, the bot responds with the name of the image file (xyz.png), But I want it to respond with an image (Display the image on UI).

What do I have to do to achieve this? I am relatively new to gradio so have been stuck for the last three days.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi i also want to achieve something similar, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @DanishZahidMalik Unfortunately, no. But you can vote for this post, so it will get highlighted to more people.

Comment: you can try below : 
````with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.ClearButton([msg, chatbot])

    def respond(message, chat_history):
        bot_message = "![your image is](https://images.pexels.com/photos/18932328/pexels-photo-18932328/free-photo-of-aerial-view-of-st-peters-square-vatican-city-rome-italy.jpeg) "
        chat_history.append((message, bot_message))
        time.sleep(2)
        return "", chat_history

    msg.submit(respond, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch() ```